# Change table width based on number of rows in another table using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-tables

My Html page has 2 tables :

- **First table** with `class='af_column_column-header-table' and` id='Table1'`.
- **Second table.**

**css :**

```
.af_column_column-header-table { 
     width = 100% !important;
 }
```

**Problem :**

- If the second table has more than one row then
  set the first table width to 99.3%.
- I want to do that for the first table only.

  PS: I have many tables on my page that uses the same style class
  `af_column_column-header-table`.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.af_column_column-header-table').rows.length` try this. Will give you the first one in the DOM. `querySelectorAll()` will give all the tables.

Comment: `if (document.getElementById("Table1").getElementsByTagName("tr").length > 0)` then change width

Comment: could you type the syntax to change the width ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `querySelectorAll` with the help of `:first-child` to select the first table, then set the style using `.style.width` :

```
var rows_count = document.querySelectorAll('table.af_column_column-header-table:first-child tr').length;

if( rows_count > 1){
  document.getElementById('Table1').style.width = '99.3%';
}
```

> i have many tables on my page that uses the same style class af_column_column-header-table i want to do that for the first table only.

That will be achiever with the use of `:first-child` selector.